# Google API Service Account - Can't Access Private Data

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

Trying to access my personal calendar data using a service account.

I've gone through the setup for creating a service account (with owner permissions).  Using NodeJS, I've successfully made requests to my public calendar, but not my private calendars.  ( the same result using `googleapis` and `google-OAuth-jwt` packages)

Everything that I've searched shows that I need to give "domain-wide authority", BUT, I do not have a G Suite account, so I don't believe this applies to me.

So the question is, can one access their own personal calendar data using a service account?  What might I be missing?

Comment: Thank you so much.  Everything is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may refer with this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40144018/access-google-calendar-api-using-service-account-authentication). It stated that the service account has its on Google calendar account so if you are trying to read one of your personal calendars, you are going to share it with the service account. You can check the example given using the [Json service account key file](http://www.daimto.com/google-service-accounts-with-json-file/).

Answer (score 0):

Answer in comments, thanks to [abielita](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5832311/abielita).  Link to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40144018/access-google-calendar-api-using-service-account-authentication).

> Remember service accounts are not you. The service account has its own Google calendar account so if you are trying to read one of your personal calendars you are going to have to share it with the service account.

Shared the calendar with my service account.